# Find string with RegEx by prefix and segments

Tags: c#, regex

We are trying to write a program that stores all variables, parameters, methods, classnames etc. of a project. Then we replace methods with the right names.
Basically I am using `Directory.GetFiles()` and `StreamReader` to read out the .CS files. Let's say the following is the result we got from reading out those .CS files:

```
string Code = @"public static void _MET_ClassName_MethodName() { var _VAR_MethodName_Foo = \"Test\"; }";
```

In reality the string `Code` is way longer and contains more method and variable definitions. In the end I am going to add parameters too and class names.

I am trying to get the method and variable name with RegEx although nothing worked and I have no idea how to achieve what I am trying. The symbol names consist of the following: `_ABC_Segment1_Segment2`. ABC can be any 3-letter value, Segment1 and Segment2 will always contain just alphanumeric characters (the length of those segments are variable) and the underscores are always there.

I tried reading up on RegEx and used regexr.com to "try out" although I never got far. Any help is appreciated.

The following I tried:

```
/_MET_([A-Z]\w+)/g
```

This isn't variable due to having `_MET_` in there fixed and it doesn't make a difference in Segment1 and Segment2.

Comment: How important is it that your list of variables, methods, etc are *accurate*?  It might suit you better to use a code parser instead of filtering the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
_[A-Za-z]{3}_[A-Za-z0-9]*_[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Breakdown

```
_                 //match first underscore
[A-Za-z]{3}       //match 3 alpha characters
_                 //match separator underscore
[A-Za-z0-9]*      //match any alpha-numeric string (segment1)
_                 //match another underscore
[A-Za-z0-9]*      //match alphanumeric string (segment2)
```

Alternatively, since it looks like the first part (the MET or VAR) is probably from a small subset of acceptable values, the following would work if you only want to match a few values in that part of the string:

```
_(MET|VAR)_[A-Za-z0-9]*_[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

The `(MET|VAR)` part matches either MET or VAR.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed description. Works like a flaw and I can learn from this.